# Import TYPO3 website without .t3d file

Tags: typo3

I have a website which was made with TYPO3 and want to import it into my local TYPO3 environment. Unfortunately the website has not been exported as .t3d file but just all the folders have been copied on a CD and the original project was deleted.
Is there a possibility to import the project manually?
I do have a sql script to create and fill the tables.

Comment: Is the last sentence a question? Do you have the SQL or not?

Comment: Without database dump you can't do anything...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I do have the SQL dump, it was no question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a working typo3 project in your local Typo3 environment, with the files and DB Dump you have:

- Get the typo3 version by looking at this file

  ```
  /t3lib/config_default.php, Line 733
  ```

  It looks like this in typo3 4.7:

  ```
  define('TYPO3_branch', '4.7');
  ```

  Now you know, that your typo3 version is 4.7
- If the typo3 version is greater than 4.7 e.g. 6.x, then we have come to a halt.
  For typo3 v6.x, the installation process is a different one. And I don’t know it.
  Still with me? **And Typo3 Version 4.7, 4.6, 4.5 or less?**
- Download a fresh copy of typo3 for this version at

  http://typo3.org/download/
  Choose “Source + Dummy”
- Install it in your local typo3 environment
- Make a backup of the new project (Files and DB)
- FILES: In the typo3 project delete this dirs

  ```
  /fileadmin
  /uploads
  /typo3conf
  ```
- FILES: Copy from your CD into the new typo3 project

  ```
  /fileadmin
  /uploads
  /typo3conf
  ```
- FILES: Delete the content of /typo3temp directory, but keep the directory.
- FILES: Delete old cache files in /typo3conf

  Their filename starts with

  ```
  temp_CACHED_.....php
  ```
- DB: Remove all tables from the (MySQL-)database of your typo3 project
- DB: Import your (MySQL-)Dump into the empty database
- Now the easy part is done :)
- Log into the typo3 install tool

  www.yourserver.tld/typo3/install/
  Password:  joh316

  Most likey, this will not let you log in.
  So you have to set a new password for the install tool
- FILES: Go to this file:

  ```
  /typo3conf/localconf.php
  ```

  Find all lines, containing

  $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['installToolPassword'] =

  Keep one, delete the others (if there are more than one, at all).
  Edit this line, so it looks like this:

  $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['installToolPassword'] = ‘f561aaf6ef0bf14d4208bb46a4ccb3ad ;

  This is the md5 hash of “xxx”.
  Thus your new password for the install tool is “xxx” (without the quotes)
- INSTALL TOOL: Log into the typo3 install tool, again

  www.yourserver.tld/typo3/install/
  Password:  xxx
- INSTALL TOOL:  Create a typo3 admin user

  Goto “Database Analyzer”
  At the bottom of the page click on “Create "admin" user”
  Enter a username and password for yourself.
  Leave the install tool
- TYPO3: Login

  www.yourserver.tld/typo3/

  Login with the admin user you have just created
- TYPO3: Go to the extension manager
  It is located in the left menu, below “Admin Tools”
  Check the list of extensions and decide, which ones you should enable.
  Click on the “gray brick” before the extension name, to enable an extension.
  The gray brick turns into a green brick.
- TYPO3: Clear all caches
  Klick on the yellow lightning symbol on top rigt of your current screen (the typo3 backend)
- Test website in browser

  Go to your website at www.yourserver.tld
  Hopefully it is working :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great tutorial to import a typo3 project. This is very detailed answer I am very happy about. I am not finished yet with the import, there seems to be problems with the mysql database version, but I am convinced this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Or simpler:

Assume that the CD is your server. The dump is already located on your CD, therefore skip step 1.

1. Make a database dump on your server.
2. Copy the folders `fileadmin, typo3conf, uploads` to your local installation.
3. Optionally, copy the file `.htaccess` file to your local installation.
4. Fetch the corresponding source for your major version (e.g. 4.5, 4.7, 6.1 or 6.2).
5. Place the folder typo3 and if it exists also the folder t3lib into your local installation.
6. Place the file index.php in your local installation. Instead of the steps 5. and 6., you can also setup a symlink installation.
7. Create a folder `typo3temp` in your local installation.
8. Import the database in your local database server.
9. Change the according database settings (server, username, port and password) in either `typo3conf/localconf.php` or `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`.
10. Check your site.